# which framework to use for a graph / dnd java web application

Tags: java, web-applications

I will need to write an interactive web application, where most of the work would be moving nodes and connecting them with other nodes by relations (graph editing). The nodes will be of different types, just as the relation will be as well. What would be your choice of a framework to use for it? It doesn't have to be a pure webapp, it can require a plugin. Some of the options would be:

- JAvaFX2
- Vaadin
- Wicket
- ...

Again, it will not be a standard database-backed application with forms and so on. Of course, there will be parts for text input (like adding values to node properties and so on).

As I can't really decide myself, maybe you would give me some tips and reasoning behind them?

wujek

Comment: and why the -1? what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/jgraph.html) is a good one. They have a Java and a Javascript version. Try it out online [here](http://www.diagram.ly/).

Comment: It is a Swing library, which would mean I will have to build a Swing app / applet (and maybe deploy via JNLP), or a JavaFX one. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yes, or... go the Javascript way :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [JIT](http://thejit.org/) - it is in javascript.
Take a look at the demos to see if it would work for you.